# adding bootstrap to magento 2

Tags: magento2, rwd

Adding the direct **bootstrap** online link conflicts with the **layout**. I've compiled bootstrap for just the responsive grid, but cannot find exactly where to place this bootstrap.min.css and how to link it from my homepage. All i want is the responsive grid. I'm running a child theme off Luma.

**Magento version 2.0.13**

Answer (score 3):

You can include it in CMS home page as follows.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Put **bootstrap.min.css** in **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/**

At last deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: ok, did that and got the following message: [InvalidArgumentException]                                              
  There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.

Comment: Please give permission to var folder.   chmod 777 -R var

Comment: and then try to deploy content again

Comment: How to add bootstrap js?

Comment: You can add it using require config js file